# How to export the vehicle telemetry data from Carla to a file (.txt, .csv. .xlsx etc.)?

Tags: python, c++, carla

With 'ShowDebugTelemetry', I'm able to display the vehicle telemetry data while running a simulation. But I want to export this data (forces generated by each tire) to an external file so that I can change the vehicle parameters and see its impact on the forces. How to do that? I was searching for the function 'ShowDebugTelemetry' in carla source code but nothing of that sort exists. How is carla computing the forces then?

Comment: Not sure where you searched, but the carla repository has plenty of hits for "ShowDebugTelemetry". There is even a [pull request](https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla/pull/5153) that allows you to pull telemetry from Python. Alternatively, you should figure out where the telemetry is being shown and modify that code to write to a file instead. All of this is is out of scope for SO, however. I suggest you do a bit more research and try to narrow down the problem to one that fits in a SO question.

Comment: Hi, I've built carla from source-code so as to be able to use unreal-engine editor as well. The "ShowDebugTelemetry" function that I could find has only boolean input/output, so if I try to access it, it gave only the status update. 
I checked the source code from the link you've shared. IDKW but I don't have the GetVehicleTelemetry & GetWheelTelemetry functions in the files that I cloned from git.
Thanks for sharing the link, I'll take a look into it.

Comment: While trying to use 'Vehicle.get_telemetry_data', I get an AttributeError: 'Vehicle' object has no attribute 'get_telemetry_data'

Comment: Yes, I linked to a pull request. That code does not yet live in the main branch of the repository. You need to check out and build the branch associated with the PR before that can work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: With the scripts available [here](https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla/tree/joel-mb/telemetry_data), I was able to use the pull request. Thanks for sharing the link.

Comment: Ok, this might be a noob question. I'm able to use the "get_telemetry_data()" function & extract the data by using:

`telemetry = world.player.get_telemetry_data()`

It creates an object & I can access VehicleTelemetryData easily. But if I want to access wheel Telemetry data using `telemetry.wheels` command, it throws this error:

`No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: class std::vector<class carla::rpc::WheelTelemetryData,class std::allocator<class carla::rpc::WheelTelemetryData> >`

How to resolve this?